# How to set `XDG_DATA_DIRS` for first `/usr/bin/gnome-shell` process?

Tags: arch-linux, environment-variables, gnome3

I want to add a path to `XDG_DATA_DIRS` as seen by `gnome-shell`. Here's what I tried so far.

I run `htop`, filter by `gnome-shell` and then pick the top most `/usr/bin/gnome-shell` with the smallest process ID (PID). I then run `sudo cat /proc/$PID/environ` and get, among others

`XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/gdm/greeter:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/`

I would like to add a path to this environment variable, so that additional icons are discovered and shown for the Gnome App Launcher. These icons reside in `home/cloud/.nix-profile/share/icons`. I tried adding `export XDG_DATA_DIRS="/home/cloud/.nix-profile/share:$XDG_DATA_DIRS"` to `/etc/profile`, `.gnomerc` and `.profile`, but nothing worked. Meaning when I repeat `htop` and `cat /proc` the value of `XDG_DATA_DIRS` as seen by `gnome-shell` is the same as before. I tried grepping for `/usr/share/gdm/greeter` but I couldn't figure out where this is currently being set

I'm using `gnome-shell 1:3.36.5-1` on `5.8.1-arch1-1`

Comment: After you added that export to `/etc/profile`, did you restart or atleast logout and back in?

Comment: Yes, I always restarted after the changes